# Magento 1.7.02 - How do I can get new entered shipping address in shipping method step

Tags: magento

As the title says, how do I can get new entered shipping address to print in shipping method.

Step in Magento 1.7.02, as you know all data in checkout is saved in javascript vars and post to the server until the order is placed, I need print the address and name in shipping method step.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
```

This would return the current session shipping address

Comment: Thanks for your response, but magento load at once -> shipping address, shipping method, payment and place order and then just hide or show the steps using javascript.

Comment: Shipping address, shipping method , payment, all are added to sales_quote. When order is placed it is converted to sales_order.

So, in shipping method step you can get current session quote value
:)

Comment: But the page with shipping method never reload again, all steps are loaded just one time and then showed via javascript.

Comment: Do you want shipping address div in shipping method or shipping address information in shipping method..

If so check aitoc checkout module

Comment: Sandeep, I need shipping address data entered in previows step to print in shipping method